# Kubernetes mutual trust using multiple intermediate certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, client-certificates, kubernetes-ingress, mutual-authentication

I am trying out a scenario where mutual trust can be established between the client and server using kubernetes ingress controller.

We have two types of clients who would access our service deployed in k8s:

1. Internal systems/users
2. External systems/users

The idea is to build a certificate chain in the following way:

1. For internal systems/users, issue client certificates signed by Internal intermediate CA (Internal intermediate CA is signed by Root CA)

   `Root CA -> Internal intermediate CA -> internal client cert`
2. For external systems/users, issue client certificates signed by External intermediate CA (External intermediate CA is signed by Internal intermediate CA)

   `Root CA -> Internal intermediate CA -> External intermediate CA -> external client cert`

How can we accomplish mutual trust for the above scenario? Can we create a `ca-cert` secret with Root CA and the two intermediate CA certs and configure it in ingress for mutual trust.

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions according to the following [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/client-certs/)?

Comment: @dinup, have you checked link from Hang Du?